# mysql_connect is not working how to fix with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

mysql_connect is not working and I don't know how to fix it with mysqli.

I have tried to degrade my PHP Version from PHP 7 to 5, but I failed either

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$query1=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");


mysql_select_db("edgedata",$query1);


$start=0;

$limit=8;


if(isset($_GET['id']))


{`
    $id=$_GET['id'];

    $start=($id-1)*$limit;
}

$query=mysql_query("select * from items LIMIT $start, $limit");

while($query2=mysql_query_fetch_array($query))
{
```

Comment: What do you mean by `not working`? Is there any error?

Comment: Also, most of the time, replace  `mysql_*` with `mysqli_*` will work

Comment: @catcon No it won't, the majority of functions had their usage changed. They require connection strings

Comment: @user3783243: yeah, forgot to mention that.

Comment: Don't downgrade. That's going the wrong way. Use the manual and find how the functions are used... or use PDO. Your current usage was open to SQL injections as well.

Comment: Thanks...The problem has already solved!.I am new to PHP programming so I don't know more about SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

I explain how to set mysqli in connection.

```
  $con=new mysqli("localhost","root","","edgedata");
   $start=0;
   $limit=8;
   if(isset($_GET['id']))
   {
    $id=$_GET['id'];

     $start=($id-1)*$limit;

    }
     $query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from items LIMIT $start, $limit");
       while($query2=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...I tried your codes and the program run for a 100% though it is somewhere show me this error message  "Call to undefined function mysql_num_row in this line of code "

$rows=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from items"));
$total=ceil($rows/$limit)

Comment: ya sure first of you can change mysql_num_rows to mysqli_num_row.

Comment: welcome alex :)